# Python rename new excel file. dr.to_excel

Tags: python, dataframe

can we rename the excel file every time we hit start python script? e.g. sample.xlsx -->sample(1).xlsx-->sample(2).xlsx

I'm trying to automatically restart the script in case of a connection error but it overwrites existing .xlsx file data.

I'm currently using this code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Student':sdetail, 'Link':link} )
    
    excelfilename = "BVL23" +".xlsx"
    df.to_excel(excelfilename, sheet_name="raport")
```

I also used the below code it works but it creates a new file every second, hour or day and this is not what I want. I only want to create a new file once my script restarts so the current file does not overwrite.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,1,1]})
    TodaysDate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    excelfilename = "raport_" +TodaysDate + str(itr) + ".xlsx"
    df.to_excel(excelfilename, sheet_name="raport", index=True)
```

here is my full script. Thanks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import urllib3, socket
from urllib3.connection import HTTPConnection
import time
import random
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import time

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0'}
HTTPConnection.default_socket_options = ( 
            HTTPConnection.default_socket_options + [
            (socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, 1000000), #1MB in byte
            (socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 1000000)
        ])

sdetail=[]
link=[]
fn = []

def getDetail(page):
    url = f'https://www.sample/Results/rollNo={page}'
    r = requests.get (url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    data2 = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'main'})
    link2=url
    link.append(link2)

    for item in data2:
        xdetail = item.h5.text
        sdetail.append(xdetail)

    data = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'fontLight'})
    for item in data:
        xdetail = item.h5.text
        sdetail.append(xdetail)

    df = pd.DataFrame({'Student':sdetail, 'Link':link} )
    
    excelfilename = "BVL23" +".xlsx"
    df.to_excel(excelfilename, sheet_name="raport")
    
    print (url)
    


    return

for x in range(1009616,2000000):
    getDetail(x)



print('finished')
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for similar features below code will help..

```
TodaysDate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
old_name = r"sample1.xlsx"
new_name = "sample2" + TodaysDate +".xlsx"
    
os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```